# Bad idea? ggplotting an S3 class object

Tags: r, ggplot2

Many R objects have S3 methods to plot associated with them.  For instance, every R regression tutorial contains something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(10))
dat$y <- dat$x+runif(10)
my.lm <- lm( y~x, dat )
plot(my.lm)
```

Which displays regression diagnostics.

Similarly, I have an S3 object for a package which consists of a list which basically holds a few time series.  I have a `plot.myobject` method for it which reaches into the list, yanks out the time series, and plots them on the same graph.  I would like to rewrite this as a ggplot2 function so that it will be prettier and perhaps more extensible as well.

Because this package is intended to get people without much R experience up and running quickly, **I'd like this to be a one-liner with one argument**, as in `plot(myobject)`, `ggplot(myobject)`, or whatever the appropriate version might be.  Then once they get hooked, they can learn more about `ggplot2` and customize the graph to their heart's content.

My initial temptation was to simply replace the internals of the `plot.myobject` method to use ggplot2.  This, however, seems like it might lose me major style points.

Is this a bad idea, and if so why and what alternative should I use?

Comment: Isn't that what `fortify` is meant for?

Comment: @joran Yes, I agree that `fortify` is meant for this.  I have tried to describe this in my answer.

Comment: @joran see my comments to Andrie's answer.  I'd like a one-liner and `fortify` doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: This is in some sense antithetical to the idea of ggplot2 which is to provide basic building blocks that you can assemble to create any type of plot.  However, I have thought about providing an `autoplot` method that would assemble a default set of blocks for common data types.

Comment: @hadley That's the conclusion that I'd reached in chat as well.  But it's clearly something people want (witness `ggheat`, `ggdendrogram`, but also `plot.lm`, etc.) and it seems to be in the spirit of `qplot`.    So I'm sympathetic to the philosophy of ggplot2, but I also really want to use your package for everything not just my own graphs. :-)

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested using `autoplot` as a function name.

Comment: @hadley: Does `autoplot` exist already?  I can't find it even using `sos::findFn`.  Should I create it, and if so as an S3 or S4 generic function?

Comment: Create it. S3.  Should have arguments `x` and `...`.  Then submit patch to ggplot2 ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per Hadley's suggestion in comments, I have submitted a generic S3 `autoplot()` to the `ggplot2` Github repository.  So if it's accepted and checks out, there should be an `autoplot` available for this use in the future.

**Update**

`autoplot` is now available in `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 12):

There is an existing idiom in `ggplot2` to do exactly what you propose.  It is called `fortify`.  It takes an object and produces a version of the object in a form that ggplot can work with, i.e. a data.frame.  Section 9.3 in Hadley's ggplot2 book describes how to do this, using the S3 object class `lm` as an example.  To see this in action, type `fortify.lm` into your console to get the following code:

```
function (model, data = model$model, ...) 
{
    infl <- influence(model, do.coef = FALSE)
    data$.hat <- infl$hat
    data$.sigma <- infl$sigma
    data$.cooksd <- cooks.distance(model, infl)
    data$.fitted <- predict(model)
    data$.resid <- resid(model)
    data$.stdresid <- rstandard(model, infl)
    data
}
<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

---

Here is my own example of writing a `fortify` method for `tree`, originally published on the [ggplot2 mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/6153bcadb715dac2/21c369d8175db3b6?lnk=gst&q=fortify%20tree#21c369d8175db3b6)

```
fortify.tree <- function(model, data, ...){
  require(tree)
  # Uses tree:::treeco to extract data frame of plot locations
  xy <- tree:::treeco(model)
  n <- model$frame$n

  # Lines copied from tree:::treepl
  x <- xy$x
  y <- xy$y
  node = as.numeric(row.names(model$frame))
  parent <- match((node%/%2), node)
  sibling <- match(ifelse(node%%2, node - 1L, node + 1L), node)

  linev <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, xend=x, yend=y[parent], n=n)
  lineh <- data.frame(x=x[parent], y=y[parent], xend=x,
      yend=y[parent], n=n)

  rbind(linev[-1,], lineh[-1,])

} 

theme_null <- opts(
    panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
    axis.text.x = theme_blank(),
    axis.text.y = theme_blank(),
    axis.ticks = theme_blank(),
    axis.title.x = theme_blank(),
    axis.title.y = theme_blank(),
    legend.position = "none"
)
```

And the plot code.  Notice that the data passed to `ggplot` is not a `data.frame` but a `tree` object.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tree)

data(cpus, package="MASS")
cpus.ltr <- tree(log10(perf) ~ syct+mmin+mmax+cach+chmin+chmax, cpus)

p <- ggplot(data=cpus.ltr) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend,size=n),
      colour="blue", alpha=0.5) + 
    scale_size("n", to=c(0, 3)) + 
    theme_null
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: As best I can tell from the documentation, generic function, and `fortify.lm`, `fortify` takes a class'd object and returns a data.frame that `ggplot2` can work with.  I can do that part already.  What I want is a one-step plot command for end-users.  E.g. I have created a `myclass` object and want to see what's inside: `magicgenericplotcommand(myobject)`.  I can sort of see how writing a `fortify.myobject` command would be a good way to get there, but it still requires way too much `ggplot2` knowledge to put as an example for a typical end-user of this package....

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I get it now.  `?fortify.lm` passes `data = fortify(mod, mtcars)` which had me confused.

Comment: You could do both (this and a `plot.myobject`).

Comment: I think the question is what is the best idiom for encapsulating the plot part you have such that you have the equivalent p with a command `p <- SomeFunction(cpus.ltr)`.  One possibility is to have a `ggplot.tree` function which returns basically this (with an explicit call to fortify), but is that the best idiom for a simple invocation to create the typical graphical expression of an object type?

Comment: @BrianDiggs See Aaron's answer and my comment.  I'm not sure that's the best way at all, since it sort of breaks the typical `ggplot` way of working.  But it's interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Using `plot.myobject` is easy to remember and execute.  However, if you're talking about `myobject`s that already have `plot.myobject` functions, you have to possibly worry about the different versions in the different namespaces.  But if it's just for your own `myobject`s, you don't lose any style points with me.  The `nlme` package, for one, does this extensively, though with lattice graphs instead of ggplot.

Using `ggplot.myobject` is an alternative; you shouldn't have to worry about other versions, unless other people start doing the same thing.  However, as you note, it does break the `ggplot` usage paradigm.

Another alternative is to use a new name, say, `gsk3plot`; you never have to worry about other versions, it's not too hard to remember, and you can make alternatives to plot to your heart's content without having to worry about conflicts.  This is probably what I'd choose as it makes it clear to the audience that these plots are customizable and this is a function that makes the plot the way that you prefer, and that if they are so inclined, they could dig in and do the same thing.

Comment: I'd looked at `qplot` and it didn't look easily extensible.  `ggplot()` does look like it just dispatches `UseMethod` (S3), but I'd sort of be breaking the metaphor by having `ggplot()` do the whole plot rather than return a plot object that then needed a `+ geom_whatever()`, right?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm tempted to go with `plot.myclass` for the simple function and then write a `fortify.myclass` to allow power users to tinker.

Comment: If it's just for your own `myclass` that's what I'd do too.

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot` and `ggplot2` methods generally expect the data to come to them in melt()-ed form. So your methods may need to do a melt (from package plyr) and then "map" the resulting column names to arguments in the ggplot methods.

Comment: This is essentially what my current plot command does.  Not a problem getting the data in the right form; the question is how to make it a one-argument plot command `__plot(myobject)` and have the correct method get dispatched.